# In SpriteKit , I add some nodes and some lighting inside the .sks file , but they are not displayed when I run the app

Tags: sprite-kit, scene

In SpriteKit in XCode 6, I add some nodes and some lighting inside the .sks - in the Scene editor, but they are not displayed when I run the app. What am I missing?

Comment: how are you loading your scene?

Comment: Like this:  
`SKScene * scene = [GameScene sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];`  
`scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;`  
`[skView presentScene:scene];`

Comment: That is why,  you are not loading the sks file at all,  create a new sprite kit project in Xcode, it will give you the template code that loads the sks file

Comment: Thanks. I can't accept your answer, since it is in a form of a comment. But creating new project and replacing that piece of code that I got from some tutorial from internet with the original did the trick somehow.

Comment: Although I am not sure what caused this, because the code for adding the scene is the same.....

Comment: I think I know. The z-position was causing elements to not appear. Changing the z-position did the trick of revealing the elements.

Comment: then sceneWithSize must be loading your sks file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The z-position was causing elements to not appear. Changing the z-position did the trick of revealing the elements.